# Text flickering when changing inline image height on scroll event on MOBILE

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome, mobile

I'm trying to create an effect similar to parallax.

When i scroll the page down on a mobile browser, i expect the image to expand (change its height).

What i don't want is the next paragraph after it (the one with the blue border) to flicker or jump.

I'm trying to achieve a smooth animation of the image and the paragraph after it.

The height is updated with this simple function on scroll event

```
function expandPic(pic, newHeight) {
if (newHeight > pic.height) {
    newHeight = pic.height;
}
pic.selector.style.height = newHeight + 'px';
}
```

please help :)

Test this on mobile browser

**here is a live example** : [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dimshik/px23zwex/)

Comment: Have you tried putting a transition: height in the CSS of the parallax element?

Comment: Yes, 
I've  tried this: "transition: height 0.1s ease;" but this only makes the jumping worse.

Comment: Chrome - works great ... Edge - text jumps ... Firefox - no image at all

Comment: This happens only on mobile devices (i tested on Chrome)